# import external header (link) in MVC4 _layout page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My company has common header that developed in php. I need to import that page into my layouts page in the project. The header can me called "company.com/inc/custom/footer2sn/"

How can call this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your page is to include is a static HTML page you can use Partial.
Simply change the somepage.html to somepage.cshtml.

Example:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Path/to/somefile.cshtml")
```

Trying to render a normal HTML file will give you an error such as Page cannot be found or no rendering engine could be found.

SO if you have a static HTML page, change the extension to CSHTML and use @Html.Partial()

OR

If the header you want to include is a PHP file it is possible as long as you have a server that is up and running and ready to serve the generated HTML from the PHP page.

You could write a custom HTML Helper

```
public static class MyHelpers
{
  public static HtmlString RenderPHP(this HtmlHelper helper, string path)
  {
    var requestContext = helper.ViewContext.RequestContext;
    UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(requestContext);
    var client = new WebClient();
    var returnString= client.DownloadString(new Uri(string.format("Http://{0}{1}",      requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host, url.Content(path))));
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(returnString);
  }
```

}

In short, this simply takes the HTML generated from the PHP page and injects it into a section within your page.

To use this inside your page use Razor Syntax like so:

```
<div id="phpPage">
   @Html.RenderPHP("company.com/inc/custom/footer2sn/somepage.php"). <!-- Note this must on a server capable of rendering the php  -->
```

[Source](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/12/10/using-classic-asp-php-and-webform-pages-in-asp-net-mvc-views.aspx)

Comment: This is exactly working what I am looking for? But header code render into my page. it has relative paths in their code like `href="/events/calendar/" `. So my local not that information because it is coming from external. How to mange this?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how MVC would handle relative paths. If I do come across something I shall let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Html.RenderPartial`:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("SomeView"); }
```

But, it's better to have your layouts inherit each other hierarchically, and put your HTML directly in the layer it belongs to for common layout elements:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            ...
        </header>

        @RenderBody()

        <footer>
            ...
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**_TwoColumnLayout.cshtml**

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }

<div id="container">

    <div id="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <aside id="sidebar">
        ...
    </aside>
</div>
```

You can keep building layers like this as deep as you need. Just set `Layout` to the template it should inherit from and then put `@RenderBody()` where the content of the next child template or view should go.

Comment: I cannot put header html. Because our webcontent team keeps changes that header. I have only option that need to call in my page.

Comment: I can't tell you what to do, but process shouldn't dictate bad design. Why can't your webcontent team work directly on layouts that are actually being used?

Comment: I don't think so. Because some other web application also using same way that including that header.